# Prove or disprove: $\Bbb{Q}(i):=\{a+ib : a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb{C},+)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove or disprove: $\Bbb{Q}(i):=\{a+ib : a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb{C},+)$.

I have that I need to find if it is associative, has an identity, and has an inverse. But I am still confused as to how to prove that.
So far I have:

Associative:

$(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$

$(a+ib)+c=a+(b+ic)$

$a+ib+ic=a+i(b+ic)$

Which automatically makes it wrong, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your definition of subgroup should give a list of conditions that must be satisfied. Which of those are you having trouble proving?

Comment: A question to start you off... Does $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ have an identity element? That is, does it have an element $e$ such that for any $r \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$, we have $e+r=r=r+e$?

Comment: I think what confused me that it is not just regular groups and subgroups. It is Q(i) and (C,+). I am not too sure exactly what this means and therefore I am not too sure where to start or what to look for.

Comment: $\Bbb Q(i)$ is defined in your first line.  It is the subset of complex numbers where both the real and imaginary parts are rational.  $\Bbb {(C,+)}$ is the group of all the complex numbers with addition the operation.

Answer (score 1):

By the subgroup criterion, it is sufficient to check that $x + y^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$. Let $x = a+ib$ and $y = c+id$ so $y^{-1} = -c-id$ (additive inverse is just the negative). Then $x+y^{-1} = (a-c) + i(b-d) \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$, so it is a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Subgroup Test: for any nonempty set $H$ of a group $G$, if for any $a,b \in H$ then $ab^{-1} \in H$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us follow the definition of subgroup. Clearly $\mathbb{Q(i)}\subset\mathbb{C}.$ If $a+ib, c+id \in \mathbb{Q(i)}$ then $a+ib+c+id=a+b+i(c+d)\in\mathbb{Q(i)}.$ Similarly associativity and commutativity also hold. $1+i0$ is the Identity element in    $\mathbb{Q(i)}.$ $a-ib   \in \mathbb{Q(i)}$ is the inverse of every  $a+ib   \in\mathbb{Q(i)}. $ $\mathbb{C}$ and      $\mathbb{Q(i)}$  are groups under the same operations. Hence $\mathbb{Q(i)}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}.$